# jCrop un restrain proportions

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, jcrop

I've built an image upload and crop application in .NET MVC4 and have the following code that I found at deepliquid.com.Aas an MVC developer I have that part working but my javascript leaves a lot to be desired. The code below constrains proportions, how can I update it so it doesn't constrain proportions yet still retain the preview?

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(function ($) {

                    // Create variables (in this scope) to hold the API and image size
                    var jcrop_api,
                        boundx,
                        boundy,

                        // Grab some information about the preview pane
                        $preview = $('#preview-pane'),
                        $pcnt = $('#preview-pane .preview-container'),
                        $pimg = $('#preview-pane .preview-container img'),

                        xsize = $pcnt.width(),
                        ysize = $pcnt.height();

                    $('#target').Jcrop({
                        onChange: updatePreview,
                        onSelect: updatePreview,
                        **aspectRatio: xsize / ysize**
                    }, function () {
                        // Use the API to get the real image size
                        var bounds = this.getBounds();
                        boundx = bounds[0];
                        boundy = bounds[1];
                        // Store the API in the jcrop_api variable
                        jcrop_api = this;

                        // Move the preview into the jcrop container for css positioning
                        $preview.appendTo(jcrop_api.ui.holder);
                    });

                    function updatePreview(c) {
                        if (parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
                            var rx = xsize / c.w;
                            var ry = ysize / c.h;

                            $pimg.css({
                                width: Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
                                height: Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
                                marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
                                marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
                            });
                        }
                    };

                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, just remove

```
aspectRatio: xsize / ysize
```